# Is it possible to identify different queries/questions in sentence?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, nlp, social-network-analysis

I want to identifies different queries in sentences.

Like - `Who is Bill Gates and where he was born?` or `Who is Bill Gates, where he was born?` contains two queries

1. Who is Bill Gates?
2. Where Bill Gates was born

I worked on Coreference resolution, so I can identify that `he` points to `Bill Gates` so resolved sentence is "Who is Bill Gates, where Bill Gates was born"

Like wise

```
MGandhi is good guys, Where he was born?
single query
who is MGandhi and where was he born?
2 queries
who is MGandhi, where he was born and died?
3 quries
India won world cup against Australia, when?
1 query (when India won WC against Auz)
```

I can perform Coreference resolution (Identifying and converting `he` to `Gandhi`) but not getting how can I distinguish queries in it.

How to do this?

I checked various sentence parser, but as this is pure nlp stuff, sentence parser does not identify it.

I tried to find "Sentence disambiguation" like "word sense disambiguation", but nothing exist like that.

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciable.

Comment: "Where **he was** born?" is not a question. "Where **was he** born?" is. Are you trying to parse poor English?

Answer (score 2):

The basic thing, you can do in that situation, is to split your query into N simple sentences each of which should be processed in order to receive YES/NO answer considering if the sentence is a query. That way you will receive following results:

```
Input: Gandhi is good guys, Where he was born?
->
Gandhi is good guys - not query
Where he was born?  - query
===
1 query

Input: who is MGandhi and where was he born?
->
who is MGandhi     - query
where was he born? - query
===
2 queries
```

This approach will require anaphora resolution (in order to convert `he` into `Gandhi` in first example) and a parser to correctly divide complex sentence into simple ones.

Comment: thanks for this. But already have completed anaphora resolution part. I already added it in question description

Comment: OvisAmmon: also `,` and `and` will not be sentence boundary in all case

Comment: I'm not sure, that your last comment makes grammatical sense. In both examples comma and conjunction `and` are exactly sentence boundary markers as they split a complex sentence into two simple ones. More of that, Stanford NLP assigns POS tag `CC` to the conjunction `and` (you can try it online @ their site). So even with anaphora present as a prerequisite, basic thing you need to learn how to do is simple sentence borders. After that your task is simplified to binary classification query/not_query.